# calculations on rows of pandas dataframe after groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, percentage

I have sales data and after adding groupby on item and Year, dataset looks as below. I want to calculate the rate of increase with the following formula

rate_of_increase = ((SalesAmount for 2019 - Sales Amount for 2018) / SalesAmount for 2018) * 100

```
      district    item  Year   salesAmount 
      Arba        coil  2019       300
                        2018       50
      Arba        pen   2019       30
                        2018       200
      Arba        hat   2019       30
                        2018       20
      Cebu        oil   2019       300
                        2018       500
      Cebu        pen   2019       120
                        2018       10
```

Output:

```
   district   item   rate_increase(%)
     Arba     coil    500
     Arba     pen    -85
     Arba     hat     50
     Cebu     oil    -40
     Cebu     pen     1100
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick (assuming your data is sorted as per your example i.e. descending by year)

```py
df=df.sort_values(by=['district', 'item','year'], ascending=False)

df["rate_increase"]=df.groupby(["district", "item"])["salesAmount"].diff().div(df["salesAmount"]).mul(-100)

df2=df.loc[df["year"].eq(2018)].drop(["year", "salesAmount"], axis=1).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Outputs:

```py
  district  item  rate_increase
0     Cebu   pen         1100.0
1     Cebu   oil          -40.0
2     Arba   pen          -85.0
3     Arba   hat           50.0
4     Arba  coil          500.0
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. COuld you please let me know how to sort the data as district(string), item (string) and Year (int). After groupby my data needs to be ordered I guess to implement your solution. Thanks

Comment: @Lilly, for sorting you can use `df.sort_values(by=['district', 'item','Year'], ascending=True, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Not the best approach but you can try this:
define a function for calculation, and apply it to your original `df`

```
def rate_of_increase(x):
    amt_2019=x[x['Year']==2019]['salesAmount']
    amt_2018=x[x['Year']==2018]['salesAmount']
    rate_of_increase = ((int(amt_2019) -int(amt_2018)) / int(amt_2018)) * 100
    return (rate_of_increase)
```

and apply to your `df` to create new dataframe

```
df2=pd.DataFrame()

df2[['district' ,'item' ,'rate']]=df.groupby(['district', 'item']).apply(lambda x: rate_of_increase(x)).reset_index()
```

**Output:**

```
   district item    rate
0   Arba    coil    500.0
1   Arba    hat     50.0
2   Arba    pen     -85.0
3   Cebu    oil     -40.0
4   Cebu    pen     1100.0
```